# C read http get response from socket in linux

Tags: c, linux, http

I want to read all the data from a socket that recived a http get reqest, be able to seprete the headers from the body, and save the body to a new file. also I need to print all the response.
I thought that I need to use an unsigned char array because I dont know if the data is a txt file or an image. my code is this:

```
unsigned char buf[2000],  half_buf[1000], *half2;
memset(buf, 0, 2000);
memset(half_buf, 0, 1000);


int n = -1, is_read = (int)read(sd, buf, 2000);
char* stat = strstr((char*)buf, "1.");
stat += 4;
int status = (int)strtol(stat, NULL, 10);
printf("%s", (char*)buf);
if(200 <= status && status < 300){

    //create folders and file
    creat_directories(full_path);

    int fd = open(full_path, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    if (fd  < 0) {
        perror("ERROR: cannot open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* end = strstr((char*)buf, "\r\n\r\n");
    while (end == NULL){
        memcpy(half_buf, buf + 1000,1000);
        memcpy(buf, half_buf,1000);
        n = (int)read(sd, buf + 1000, 1000);
        if(n == 0){
            break;
        }
        half2 = buf + 1000;
        printf("%s", half2);
        is_read += n;
        end = strstr((char*)buf, "\r\n\r\n");
    }

    end += 4;
    write(fd, end, strlen(end));
    while(n != 0){
        n = (int)read(sd, buf, 2000);
        printf("%s", buf);
        is_read += n;
        write(fd, buf, 2000);
    }
```

I am trying to serch for the end of the headers, and then to open path and file to save the body (if the response is 200 type). the problem is I have a valgrind error about uninitialized memory, and also i dont save all the data somehow (I cant open an image that I saved).
so in the under line:
how to read a data from socket, where I need to save the body but nt the headers, and also print all the respone?
Thank you

Comment: You are reading `is_read = (int)read(sd, buf, 2000);` potentially binary data and not checking the result. This data may not be null-terminated, meaning you should not run C string functions on it, like `strstr((char*)buf, "1.");`. Those assume strings terminated with a `'\0'` character.

Comment: I thought to enter null-terminated, but this will cause poblems in the process of saving data. the strstr is just to check the status (200 or somthing else). those the casting isnt enough?

Comment: Will casting a pointer change the contents of the memory that it points to?

Comment: you are right. I will try to add null terminator and see how its go